# Finger Gesture in TabBar

Tags: iphone

I have to create a Tab bar. If I do a single tap on the tab bar, the label should read some quote.

Similarly it should recognize these touch gestures and display the text in the label :

1) double tap

2) 1 finger : top to bottom swipe.

How can I do this?

Comment: When my finger gestures, it usually ends up with me being on the wrong end of a law-suit.

Comment: But seriously, check out the [`UIGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

For taps, you could use `[UITapGestureRecognzer][1]`

For swipes you could use `[UISwipeGestureRecognizer][2]`

For all the available gestures check out the `[UIGestureRecognizer][3]` docs

You would add these gesture recognizers to a `UIView` using the `addGestureRecognizer` method